Can't get fopen_s to work in new Visual Studio MFC project
I am trying to use some code that works fine in an earlier Visual Studio MFC project, but I can not get fopen_s() to work in a new Visual Studio MFC project. It refuses to open files. I can get a CFile operation to open files, but I need to use the fgetc() function and don't know how to use it with CFile.
Is there a solution?
CString fname = "some known file with path";

FILE* stream;

if (fopen_s(&stream, fname, "r") != NULL)


"It refuses to open files": What is your evidence for this?

fopen_s() is a C function returning an error-code - you can just examine it. Most usual causes of failure are bad filename (or using a relative path but the app's current folder is not the same as assumed), no rights or sharing violation. A side note, why do you want to use fgetc()? Is this a text-file? Text files are best read line-by-line, while binary files are usually read in blocks. You also rather need to supply more info for open mode, and not just "r"; text/binary at least, maybe unicode/UTF-8/UTF-16 as well. Check the documentation.

Use errno_t error_code = fopen_s(&stream, fname, "r");, put a break point there and examine error_code. The documentation will tell you more.

fopen_s returns an error code, where 0 is success. By checking if the return value is not equal to NULL, you are checking if fopen_s failed, not succeeded. Is that what you want?
